# How to give a javascript-created button the onClick attribute?

Tags: javascript, html

I am very new to JS and do not have much knowledge in it, but how do I make it so this button, when clicked, runs the functions `startBattle()`?

```
startGame = () => {
  charChoice1 = char[Math.floor(Math.random() * char.length)];
  document.getElementById("log").innerHTML = "Your character: " + charChoice1;
  charChoice2 = char[Math.floor(Math.random() * char.length)];
  document.getElementById("log").textContent += " Enemy character: " + charChoice2;
  var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
  var t = document.createTextNode("Continue");
  //add button functionallity
};

startBattle = () => {
    getElementById("log").innerHTML = "Function Run."
}
```

Comment: `btn.onclick = startBattle()`

Comment: @AnimeshSingh did we just copy PredatorIWD s answer?

Comment: @bub just show that, :P

Answer (score 1):

Like so:

```
btn.onclick = startBattle;
```

Edit: Try it like this: (doesn't work)

```
startGame = () => {
    charChoice1 = char[Math.floor(Math.random() * char.length)];
    document.getElementById("log").innerHTML = "Your character: " + charChoice1;
    charChoice2 = char[Math.floor(Math.random() * char.length)];
    document.getElementById("log").textContent += " Enemy character: " + charChoice2;
    var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
    var t = document.createTextNode("Continue");
    btn.appendChild(t);
    btn.onclick = function(){
        document.getElementById("log").innerHTML = "Function Run.";
    };
};
```

Comment: This prevents the button from being created for some reason.

Comment: @EnderShot355 Any error occurring? Try the code from the updated answer.

Comment: @EnderShot355 are you appending the btn to body? `document.body.appendChild(btn);` ?

Comment: @PredatorIWD "ReferenceError: getElementById is not defined'

Comment: @EnderShot355 Yeah I didn't see you didn't have `document` in front of that `.getElementById`.

Comment: Edit still doesnt create a button

Comment: @EnderShot355 Where are you running this code? Any html that you can post?

Comment: When button is appended it does not have text inside.

Comment: Running it from JSfiddle, have a small bit of html. @PredatorIWD

Comment: @EnderShot355 Yeah you didnt append the text to the btn. I added `btn.appendChild(t);`.

Comment: <body>
  <h1>
    Battle Game (WIP)
  </h1>
  <p>
    Press the button below to continue.
  </p>
  <button onClick=startGame();>
    Click me to start
  </button>
  <p id="log">

  </p>
</body>

Comment: @EnderShot355 You should research some more on making these kind of small js games, check out some examples and then try from scratch. I'll help if you get stuck after that.

Answer (score 1):

Add the method you intend to call on onClick event

```
var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
btn.onclick = startBattle;
```

Comment: `startBattle()`

Comment: this is the correct answer as if you add () to the end of startBattle you are telling JavaScript to execute startBattle and pass the result to the onclick event instead of assigning the startBattle method to the onclick event.